# Citation not correctly shown ( additional "(," )

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I have noticed several citation I have in a paper I'm writing do not show correcly: additional `(,` appear in citations ...

Examples:

[image: bib entry]

```
%MatlabSignalAnalysis
@misc{MatlabSignalAnalysis,
  author  = "Mathworks",
  title         = "Practical Introduction to Time-Frequency Analysis",
  howpublished  = "https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/practical-introduction-to-time-frequency-analysis.html",
  year          = "2018"
}
```

[image: bib entry two]

```
%Duarte12
@INPROCEEDINGS{Duarte12, 
author      = "C. Duarte and P. Delmar and K. W. Goossen and K. Barner and E. Gomez-Luna", 
booktitle   = "2012 Future of Instrumentation International Workshop (FIIW) Proceedings", 
title       = "Non-intrusive load monitoring based on switching voltage transients and wavelet transforms", 
pages       = "1-4", 
year        = "2012"
}
```

Any help?

**Edit:**
I am using a `cta-author` document class and a `iet` bibliography style.

```
\documentclass{cta-author}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\graphicspath{ {Pictures/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\showboxdepth=5
\showboxbreadth=5
```

When I am citing a document I use `\cite{Duarte12}`:

```
As shown in the literature \cite{Srinivasan06, Duarte12, Lin14}, transients are useful features for the task of loads' identification and disaggregation.
```

Comment: Where are `cta-author.cls` and `iet.bst` available?

Comment: They are from the IET template [link](https://digital-library.theiet.org/journals/author-guide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, based on the class `cta-author.cls` of [IET](https://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_ResearchJournals_latex.zip) and the included file `iet.bst` there 
I created the following mwe for testing purposes:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{MatlabSignalAnalysis,
  author        = "Mathworks",
  title         = "Practical Introduction to Time-Frequency Analysis",
  howpublished  = "https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/practical-introduction-to-time-frequency-analysis.html",
  year          = "2018",
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Duarte12, 
  author      = "C. Duarte and P. Delmar and K. W. Goossen and K. Barner and E. Gomez-Luna", 
  booktitle   = "2012 Future of Instrumentation International Workshop (FIIW) Proceedings", 
  title       = "Non-intrusive load monitoring based on switching voltage transients and wavelet transforms", 
  pages       = "1-4", 
  year        = "2012",
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{cta-author}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\graphicspath{ {Pictures/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\showboxdepth=5
\showboxbreadth=5


\begin{document}

\supertitle{Super Title}

\title{The Title of the Paper}

\author{\au{John Doe$^{1,2}$} \au{Eva Musterfrau$^1$} \au{Max Mustermann$^2$}}

\address{\add{1}{Faculty of Engineering and IT, University of Technology, Sydney PO Box 123, Broadway, NSW 2007, Australia}
\add{2}{Shanghai Institute of Applied Mathematics and Mechanics and Shanghai Key Laboratory of Mechanics in Energy Engineering, Shanghai University, Shanghai, 200072, People's Republic of China}
\email{shanchengcheng2010@163.com}}

\begin{abstract}
\looseness=-1 The second-order consensus of multiple
interacting non-identical agents with non-linear protocols is studied in this article.
Firstly, it is shown that all agents with different non-linear
dynamics can achieve consensus without a leader. Secondly, an
explicit expression of the consensus value is analytically developed
for the group of all agents. Thirdly, for the consensus of multiple
agents with a leader, it is proved that each agent can track the
position and velocity of the leader, which are different from those
of the follower agents. Finally, numerical simulations are given to
illustrate the theoretical results.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

As shown in the literature \cite{Srinivasan06,Duarte12,Lin14}, 
transients are useful features for the task of loads' identification 
and disaggregation.

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{iet} % iet.bst 
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

gives you compiling the following warnings

```
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Srinivasan06"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Lin14"
Warning--empty author and editor in MatlabSignalAnalysis
Warning--missing publisher in MatlabSignalAnalysis
(There were 4 warnings)
```

and the following resulting bibliography:

[image: resulting wrong bibliography]

As you can see because the publisher is missing you get the opening `(` followed by an comma.

Now let us add the missing publisher (and editor) into the bib file for **both** bib entrys. See the following mwe

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{MatlabSignalAnalysis,
  author        = "Mathworks",
  editor        = "Mathworks",
  publisher     = "Mathworks",
  title         = "Practical Introduction to Time-Frequency Analysis",
  howpublished  = "https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/practical-introduction-to-time-frequency-analysis.html",
  year          = "2018",
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Duarte12, 
  author      = "C. Duarte and P. Delmar and K. W. Goossen and K. Barner and E. Gomez-Luna", 
  booktitle   = "2012 Future of Instrumentation International Workshop (FIIW) Proceedings", 
  title       = "Non-intrusive load monitoring based on switching voltage transients and wavelet transforms", 
  publisher   = "Publisher",
  pages       = "1-4", 
  year        = "2012",
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{cta-author} 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\graphicspath{ {Pictures/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\showboxdepth=5
\showboxbreadth=5


\begin{document}

\supertitle{Super Title}

\title{The Title of the Paper}

\author{\au{John Doe$^{1,2}$} \au{Eva Musterfrau$^1$} \au{Max Mustermann$^2$}}

\address{\add{1}{Faculty of Engineering and IT, University of Technology, Sydney PO Box 123, Broadway, NSW 2007, Australia}
\add{2}{Shanghai Institute of Applied Mathematics and Mechanics and Shanghai Key Laboratory of Mechanics in Energy Engineering, Shanghai University, Shanghai, 200072, People's Republic of China}
\email{shanchengcheng2010@163.com}}

\begin{abstract}
\looseness=-1 The second-order consensus of multiple
interacting non-identical agents with non-linear protocols is studied in this article.
Firstly, it is shown that all agents with different non-linear
dynamics can achieve consensus without a leader. Secondly, an
explicit expression of the consensus value is analytically developed
for the group of all agents. Thirdly, for the consensus of multiple
agents with a leader, it is proved that each agent can track the
position and velocity of the leader, which are different from those
of the follower agents. Finally, numerical simulations are given to
illustrate the theoretical results.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

As shown in the literature \cite{%
% Srinivasan06, 
  Duarte12%, 
% Lin14
}, 
transients are useful features for the task of loads' identification 
and disaggregation.

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{iet} % iet plain
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

compiling without warnings for the bibliography and the following -- still wrong! -- bibliography:

[image: resulting wrong bibliography]

As you can see the opening `(` is now followed by the publisher, but it is not closed after the year. **That is simply a bug in `iet.bst` you should report to the class maintainer!**

For a simple test use style `plain` instead `iet` showing no error in bibliography ...

Comment: +1 The class is also a bit of a disaster.